# Interact with remote "shell" from background script via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, script

I need to emulate the following with a script which is invoked by a web service run from a Linux server:

- Access remote AIX server via SSH
- Log into an Intersystems Cache instance (if that's unfamiliar, pretend we're loading an interactive Python or Ruby [irb] environment)
- Execute commands
- Execute more commands depending on output of previous commands
- Log all input to and output from this environment

This is fairly trivial to do in C# with the SSH.NET library.  Open a shellstream to the remote host, attach a StreamReader and StreamWriter, then send input to the SSH connection via StreamWriter and read output from it via StreamReader.

How should I go about this on a Linux server with ssh?  I am experimenting with screen, but it seems more designed more for human-interactive use than by scripts, and I wonder if I am barking up the wrong tree.

I don't have control over what's installed on the AIX server.  I might be able to get things installed there but no guarantees.

Much later edit: possible solutions include pexpect/pxssh (Python), paramiko (also Python)

Comment: did you check expect or pexpect(python) ?

Comment: While this question is perfectly on topic and welcome to stay here, there are a lot more Unix users on our sister site [unix.se]. If you don't get a useful answer here after a while, consider flagging this for moderator attention and asking them to migrate it over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, screen is not the way. I don't know about `cache` but can you write a script for it or do you *need* the interactive shell? If you can write a script and save it on the AIX machine, you should be able to do

```
ssh user@aix.server.com /path/to/cache_script
```

Another approach would be to use [`expect`](http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Expect) which is also available on AIX but I can't give you more details without knowing the commands you need to run. In any case, `expect` allows you to send commands and respond to output, interacting with an interactive shell in a non-interactive way.

Comment: pexpect and pxssh look like they'll be magic for this and test well. No need to run anything (even expect) on the remote host.  Thanks for both people's replies.